# Использование NodeJS на виртуальном хостинге без ввода порта

Tags: node.js, nginx

Делаю свои первые детские шаги в мире nodejs и сразу возникают первые детские вопросы.

Установил ноду на виртуальный хостинг, создал субдомен для тестирования, в нем создал файл **hello.js**:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'sub2.mydomain.com';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Когда в терминале Putty через `cd sub2.mydomain.com` перехожу в субдомен и запускаю

```
node hello.js
```

то успешно получаю

```
Server running at http://sub2.mydomain.com:3000
```

Но теперь главный вопрос: а как мне собственно вывести Hello World! в самом браузере? Если пройти по ссылке http://sub2.mydomain.com то вижу список файлов точнее файл hello.js В доках вижу что нужно добавлять еще порт, но как вывести ответ сервера без порта? Люди ведь когда на сайты заходят никакие порты не вводят

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема. Как мне кажется. Оказалось, что провайдер, по-умолчанию, установил `ngnix`. Пришлось учить и составлять файл-конфигурации `nginx` чтобы он перенаправлял запросы с порта 80, на нужный мне порт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось не нужно вообще трогать порт 80. Достаточно в файле `.htaccess` прописать:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub2.mydomain.com:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub2.mydomain.com:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Таким образом сайт на базе NodeJS на обычном виртуальном хостинге с Apache можно открывать в браузере без указания каких либо портов после домена.

Comment: Лучше nginx....

Comment: @andreymal на виртуальном хостинге нету root-прав чтобы установить и настроить nginx

Answer (score 3):

По-хорошему, ставим nginx. Открываем **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**, пишем:

```
upstream mynode {
  keepalive 100;
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub2.mydomain.com;

        keepalive_timeout 3600;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass          http://mynode ;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
}
```

Если Apache использует 80 порт, то нельзя больше ничего на него повесить.

Ну так можно сразу открывать http://sub2.mydomain.com:3000, тогда вам ни апач, ни nginx не нужен, как и безопасность.

Comment: @stckvrw порт может контролироваться только одним приложением в системе. Если Апач его занял, то другое приложение его не сможет использовать. Но в настройках nginx, к примеру, можно какие-то поддомены перенаправить на другой порт (на тот же апач).

Comment: @stckvrw а что в ответах в консоли браузера?

Comment: @stckvrw ну и да, как вы запустили сервер?

Comment: `nohup node hello.js &` напишите, `node hello.js` запускает сервер только в текущей сессии.

Comment: @stckvrw `sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':80'` что выдаёт?

Comment: @stckvrw уверены, что с `nohup node hello.js &` не открывается?

Comment: @stckvrw у вас на каждый домен своя виртуалка?

Comment: @stckvrw вы с помощью Putty  подсоединяетесь к одному и тому же ip, на нём все субдомены висят?

Comment: @stckvrw вообще, это уже по-идеи совсем другая тема и лучше отдельным вопросом задать.

Comment: @stckvrw зачееееем? Не надо ничего из исходников ставить. Используйте `apt-get install nginx`. Проверить статус так `service nginx status`.

Comment: @stckvrw эм, у вас там что за ось стоит? Не Ubuntu?

Comment: @stckvrw у вас в коде `const port = 3000;` поменяйте на `const port =  80;`

Comment: @stckvrw `forever list`, а затем остановите текущее приложение `forever stop 0`, где вместо `0` подставьте id нужный из списка. Затем заново запустите.

Comment: @stckvrw ага, именно поэтому. Вы уж определитесь )

Comment: Уточню: хотелось бы пока оставить и Апачи под 80-м, и ноду подключить к порту 80. Подскажите как nginx установить если apt-get и yum у меня not found?

Comment: @stckvrw это лучше отдельным вопросом спросить. Я лично на серваках только с Ubuntu работал, так что не отвечу.

Comment: Оказывается что yum как и sudo т.е. команды админа на виртуальном хостинге недоступны, ведь на этом же сервере еще сотни аккаунтов других пользователей. Также (читал что) для настройки портов < 1024 как и (проверил) для доступа к /usr/local/bin тоже нужны права root/admin. В общем правильно ли понимаю: заходить на сайты под NodeJS, которые на виртуальном хостинге, привычным способом без указания после домена хвоста в виде :XXXX невозможно? (что конечно печально) Нужен или VPS/VDS или же виртуальный хостинг, но где NodeJS УЖЕ настроен под порт 80, всё верно?

Comment: @stckvrw на отдельной VPS вы сам себе хозяин, можете делать, что угодно. Node.js не настраивается на конкретный порт, вы в своём приложении можете использовать любой порт.

Comment: Да, можно любой порт, но получается что посетителям чтобы зайти на сайт, который сделан на базе NodeJS, нужно после домена указывать этот порт в адресной строке? Т.е. mydomain.com:3000 или mydomain.com:3000/kontakty... А чтобы порт в адресной строке не указывать нужно переключить ноду на порт 80. Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @stckvrw или ваше nodejs приложение запустить и там указать 80 порт, или запустить на 3000 порту, поставить nginx, а в нём проксировать запросы для этого домена на 3000 порт ноды, как я в ответе указал.